# IF AND statement where all three conditions are met

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010

I have an IF AND statement i am using .

I am trying to ensure that all conditions are met for it to be true. I am failing at this . Please see my Formula below:

```
=IF(AND(E5="Yes",F5="Closed",AND( G5="No")),"Found the guy","That isn’t him")
```

**Problem :** The above formula is not returning the correct value. For example the above formula should return "Found the guy" ie all Conditions have been satisfied.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Why are you using 2 "And"s?

Comment: Is it matching when it shouldn't, or not matching when it should? Remember to be  specific when asking for help - you may have been staring at this for hours, but we have only the information you give us to understand the problem.

Comment: @IMSoP its not matching. Therefore in the above formula i should be getting "found the guy" but i am not

Comment: @pnuts when the formula says" found the guy"  that means all conditions have been satisfied ie True.

Comment: @punts The issue is with G5 , i did a trail and error

Comment: @pnuts i tried the above i was not successful

Comment: @pnuts no its not . It has a drop down list option

Comment: Inside the formula on the formula bar, highlight G5 using your mouse and press the F9 key. What value does it show?

Comment: @rwilson its showing no

Comment: Ok. Now lets start over. First highlight G5="No" and press the F9 key. This should return TRUE. If it returns false, then there is not an exact match and there is something different with one of the values. Perhaps a leading or trailing space. Next, highlight F5="Closed" and repeat the same action. Lastly, do the same with E5="Yes". At this point you should definitely be able to see what's wrong.

Comment: You can click on the cell where your formula is and use the Evaluate Formula Window (Forumulas tab => Evaluate Formula) to step through the formula. The box is pretty small though so I usually prefer to just use the formula bar for debugging.

Comment: Got it. I was just going through the steps that I normally go through when debugging. The use of the F9 key, etc.

Comment: @rwilson i followed the above steps. G5="No" is returning False. All others are returning true

Comment: @rwilson i solved the formula. I remove the drop down list and replaced it again, then the formula worked thanks

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to have more than one AND. If all are True, the AND statement is true.
    =IF(AND(E5="Yes", F5="Closed", G5="No"),"Found the guy","That isn’t him")

Comment: It does work for me. If that is not the case for OP, maybe there is some whitespace in E5, F5 or G5?

Comment: @Andreas i had tried that before , it did not work for me

Comment: @Andreas that formula works if i remove the data validation and replace it when the formula has been implemented.